# Multiple selection change only after mouse leave

Tags: angular-material

Is it possible to trigger the selection change only when mouse leaves the select dropdown?  Using the example below, when I use "multiple" and user checks on one option, I immediately get the change event after each selection.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" (change)=onChange($event) multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Also, when I used `(selectionChange)="onChange($event)"`, the same behavior.  I also tried to listen to `optionSelectionChanges`, this time around I get 2 events per selection.

What I need is user can do multiple selection, but I will only listen after he made all the selections (like when the select dropdown closes after mouse leave).

Comment: Have added an answer! please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could bind to the `openedChange` event that fires when the select panel toggles:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Toppings"
        (openedChange)="panelChange($event)" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
            {{topping}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

panelChange(panelOpen: boolean) {
    if (!panelOpen) {
        // Panel was closed - now handle the user's selected options
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly:

You can use `(mouseover)` and `(mouseout)`

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" (mouseover)="onMouseMove(true)" (mouseout)="onMouseMove(false)" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS code:

```
onMouseMove(event) {
    console.log(event)  // true false
    // if true then the mouse is on control and false when you leave the mouse
}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbfjuy)